How to resolve "SSL handshake failed" error when using Penthouse Critical CSS generator (on Node.js)?
I want to create a Gulp task that generates a file with my site's Critical CSS. Penthouse seems to fit exactly what I need.
I can achieve generating the Critical CSS file with http://google.com, and by pointing to a local file, but not with any other external site, including my site. Whenever I attempt to run Penthouse I get the error:
Error: Error opening url 'https://www.example.com/': SSL handshake failed
This occurs no matter if url I supply is https or http.
I know Penthouse uses Puppeteer and have followed instructions on how to include a ignoreHTTPSErrors setting but this makes no difference.
Would any know what I can do to resolve this issue?
My gulpfile.js code is:
const gulp = require('gulp');
const criticalCss = require('gulp-penthouse');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer') // installed by penthouse

const browserPromise = puppeteer.launch({
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    args: ['--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--no-sandbox'],
  })

gulp.task('critical-css', function () {
    return gulp.src('./minified/lintedmain.min.css')
        .pipe(criticalCss({
            out: 'critical.css', // output file name
            url: 'http://www.example.com/', // url from where we want penthouse to extract critical styles
            width: 1400, // max window width for critical media queries
            height: 900, // max window height for critical media queries
            userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)', // pretend to be googlebot when grabbing critical page styles.
            puppeteer: {
                 getBrowser: () => browserPromise,
                 pageGotoOptions: {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'}
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./critical/')); // destination folder for the output file
});

